# I cannot get selenium to click on these input radios to save my life on the. Im trying to created an automatic job app applyer in linkedIn

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
def job_filtering(self):
    try:
        print("Clicking on Time Posted filter...")

        # Click on the "Time Posted" filter
        time_filter = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#searchFilter_timePostedRange, #searchFilter_timePostedRange-trigger')))
        time_filter.click()

        # Locate the "Past Week" option using a relative XPath expression
        past_week_option = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'timePostedRange-r604800')) or
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'timePostedRange-trigger')) or
            EC.element_to_be_clickable(('value', 'r604800')) or
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="timePostedRange-r604800"]')) and
            self.driver.find_element('type', 'radio')

        )
        past_week_option.click()
      
        sumbition_filter = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember1266"]'))
        )
        sumbition_filter.click()

        print("Selected 'Past Week' option successfully.")

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout occurred while waiting for time posted filter.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error interacting with the time posted filter:", e)

    try:
        print("Clicking on Experience Level filter...")
        exp_filter = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'searchFilter_experience')))
        exp_filter.click()

        for exp_level in ['Internship', 'Entry level', 'Associate']:
            exp_option = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'//label[contains(text(), "{exp_level}")]')))
            exp_option.click()
            print(f"Selected {exp_level} option successfully.")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Timeout occurred while waiting for experience level filter.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error interacting with the experience level filter:", e)
```

I was trying to click on the radio inputs under the Date Posted tab and the experience level on linked in. But for some reason I cannot get selenium to click on the buttons.  I have when to every selector possible and used both xpath and full xpath to try and select them but it does not work

Comment: "but it does not work" is not a good description of the problem.  If you get an error, or other unexpected results, you need to show those.  Otherwise we're just guessing what the actual problem is.